# Since 3.5.2 unable to add more grid fields

Tags: grid

Since 3.5.2 i'm unable to add more grid fields.
Did a fresh install of EE 3.5.2 and created a grid custom field.
Then i edited the grid field to have more then one column but the new column does not save. No matter which type of custom field i choose to add within the grid field.

Comment: Same problem here!.. did you resolve the problem? i'm using 3.5.2 also

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with 3.5.2... It wouldn't save my new grid layout so I ended up having to delete the field group and redo it with updated grid layout and that seemed to work.  must be a bug